# How to hide files from Bash?

Tags: bash, cygwin

On the Git Bash shell on Windows, I'm stuck looking at crap left by Windows in my home directory:

```
NTUSER.DAT
NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TM.blf
NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
```

Is there any way of hiding the files from the shell?  Any way to make Bash ignore certain files or files that match a certain regex (without having to create kludgey aliases for `ls`, `grep`, and every other command that lists files in some way/shape/fashion)?

They are already hidden from Windows Explorer, so I'm doubtful that anything done on the Windows side of things will have any effect.

Comment: The title mentions Linux but the rest of the post indicates that it's just bash on Windows.

Comment: @jordanm presumably the idea is that GNU/Linux and Git Bash share GNU tools.

Comment: @iconoclast: If you want your question to be reopened, add the Cygwin tag.

Comment: okay... done...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any such command that affects the shell and all the UNIX utilities like `ls` that deal with file names.  `SetFile` doesn't even do that under Mac OS; it only affects what Finder displays.  `bash` and other command line based shell will still display files hidden by `SetFile`.

However, `bash` has a two configuration variables that might interest you:

```
  FIGNORE
          A colon-separated list of suffixes to ignore when performing
          filename completion (see READLINE below).  A filename  whose
          suffix  matches  one  of  the entries in FIGNORE is excluded
          from the list of  matched  filenames.   A  sample  value  is
          ".o:~".
   GLOBIGNORE
          A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of file-
          names to be ignored by pathname expansion.   If  a  filename
          matched  by a pathname expansion pattern also matches one of
          the patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the  list  of
          matches.
```

Comment: D'oh! yes you're right... I forgot that on my Mac I'm usually trying to hide Unix stuff from the window manager, not the other way 'round.  Other than `.DS_Store` OS X doesn't leave its turds lying around, at least not in the home directory.  I've corrected the question.